# How to define an extern value that is an array of a struct that is from a namespace in Header

Tags: c++, namespaces

Hello community I am having questions of how to include a struct array member that is from a namespace in Header file, I am having issue as below, how could I make this work? Drawing_monster_space is namespace and S_monsters monsters is a struct.

```
#ifdef GLOBAL
Drawing_monster_space::S_monsters monsters[MAX_ENEMY_COUNT];

#else
extern Drawing_monster_space::S_monsters monsters[MAX_ENEMY_COUNT];
#endif

namespace Drawing_type_space {
namespace Monster_space {      
    struct S_monsters {
        Math_matrix4x4_space::Matrix_4x4 transform_matrix;
        Math_vector2D_space::Vector2D monsters_vec_arr[3];
        float current_pos[4];
        float center_posX;
        float center_posY;
        float next_posX;
        float next_posY;
        int way_point_index;
        bool is_collided = false;
    };
}
}

namespace Drawing_monster_space = Drawing_type_space::Monster_space;
```

Comment: It should be `S_monsters Drawing_monster_space::monsters[MAX_ENEMY_COUNT];`? The scope should go right before the variable name.

Comment: I think it should be `extern Drawing_monster_space::S_monsters Drawing_monster_space::monsters[MAX_ENEMY_COUNT];` or `namespace Drawing_monster_space { extern S_monsters monsters[MAX_ENEMY_COUNT]; }`, if the structure and the variable are both defined inside the namespace.

Comment: Hello nothing worked, the struct is inside into a namespace called  Drawing_monster_space which is a nested one, I want to use it the array member of that struct as global but no idea.

Comment: @hello Could you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ok, edited, the problem is happening in the header file where I am instantiating in #else